# How to use a URL like a parameter

Tags: java, url, servlets

I want a simple servlet that can be used without parameters. Something like :

```
http://servername:8080/do/view/username/address
```

and use it like a parameter :

```
http://servername:8080/do?action=view&login=username&page=address
```

Both urls will have the same behaviour. I prefer don't use any framework, only servlets and filters.

How can I obtain the url name from the servlet? What's the best solution?

---

## **Response:**

---

Based on the reply made by @BalusC i have created the following servlet that do all i want:

```
@WebServlet("/do/*")
public class ActionTestCasesServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  
{
  String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
  String[] parts = pathInfo.substring(1).split("/");
  RequestDispatcher destination = getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher("/" + parts[0] + ".jsp");
  if (parts.length > 1) {
request.setAttribute("username", parts[1]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 2) {
    request.setAttribute("page", parts[2]);
  }
  destination.forward(request, response);

 }
}
```

This code call the "view.jsp" passing the attributes "username" and "page".

Comment: Its in the HttpRequest passed to the servlet methods. Look up the contents of that to find it.

Comment: Use a filter to parse the url into parts. Put those parts into the request attributes so that they are available in your servlet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just map the servlet on `/do/*` instead of `/do`.

```
@WebServlet("/do/*")
```

This way you can obtain the path information using [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29).

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // /view/username/address
```

You can use the usual `String` methods like [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split it in fragments.

```
String[] parts = pathInfo.substring(1).split("/"); // view, username, address
```

#### See also:

- [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297) - for the case you intend to homegrow MVC (note: I don't recommend this, it's fun if it's for learning/hobby purposes, but if it's for real job, rather pick an existing MVC framework so that you can ensure that every pitfall is covered)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, i don't want create my homegrow MCV, i only need a  page with two or three concrete actions which are easy to remember / understand. Your solution appear very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You say you'd prefer not to use "any framework, only servlets and filters", but have you considered the [tuckey.org UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)?  This is a single filter that you can register in web.xml and then declare rules such as

```
    <rule>
        <from>/do/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)</from>
        <to>/do?action=$1&amp;login=$2&amp;page=$3</to>
    </rule>
```

in an XML file.  Then you just write your servlets to expect the query parameters as normal and let the filter deal with the "pretty" URLs.

Comment: Very interesting. I will check it, but i don't want 3pp elements. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC do it very very good. But if you do not want to use third-party frameworks all you can is handle request.getRequestURI(), split this string and do what you want. For example you can use pattern /entity/action.

Answer (score 0):

I think previous threads reply are the perfect solution. I played with web.xml file to see what I can do for and here is my results. I was able to change the web.xml to get a url similar to what you want "`http://localhost:8080/do/myServlet.do`". Here is web.xml file content which pertains to the servlet-name and url-pattern.

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>do</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>ControlServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>do</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/myServlet.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please provide explanation if you mark it down...thanks. So, I can revise it accordingly.

Comment: You're not specifically answering the concrete question at all. You're merely stabbing in the dark and pasting an unnecessarily large block of code of which you guessed/hoped that the right lines of code would be among them. This is simply noisy and unhelpful. See also the tooltip of the downvote button.

Comment: @BalusC , thank you for feedback. I modified my answer based on your feedback. I know the first time around that I read the question, I did not read it carefully. So, thank you for helping me to better help others :)

Comment: You're still not answering the concrete question. OP does not seem to want to use URLs with extensions either. See my answer for the expected answer.